# Blazor - Binding Blazor Component or workaround [ask from WPF guy]

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, data-binding, blazor

I am looking for something like this in the WPF for Blazor, if is it possible:

WPF:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding LicensesText}" />




public LicensesText LicensesText { get; set; }

ctor()
{
    LicensesText licensesText = new LicensesText();
    licensesText.ClickedShowComparision += () => { Licenses = new Licences(); };
    LicensesText = licensesText;

    //Sleep for 5 seconds
    List<LicensesText> list = new ();
    list.Add(licensesText);

    LicensesText licensesText1 = new LicensesText();
    licensesText1.ClickedShowComparision += () => { Licenses = new Licences(); };
    LicensesText = licensesText1;

    //Sleep for 5 seconds
    LicensesText = list.First();}
}
```

The Best would be something like this:

BLAZOR:

SaySomething.razor

```
<h3>@Label</h3>


@code {

    public string Label { get; set; } = "Default Label";

    public void SetLabel(string label)
    {
        Label = label;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@SaySometing

@code
{
    public SaySometing SaySometing { get; set; } = new SaySometing();
}
```

But for sure it doesn't work like it.

I come to some solution but all of them are imperfect. And I dont know how to visualize for example already created ComponentBase element, if is it possible.

```
@page "/"

@DynamicRender
<SaySometing @ref="SaySometing" />
<DynamicComponent Type="typeof(SaySometing)" @ref="DynamicComponent"></DynamicComponent>


<button @onclick="args => ChangeText(args)">Click Me!</button>

@code
{


    public SaySometing SaySometing { get; set; } = new SaySometing();

    public SaySometing SaySometing1 { get; set; } = new SaySometing();

    public DynamicComponent DynamicComponent { get; set; } = new DynamicComponent();

    private RenderFragment DynamicRender { get; set; }


    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        DynamicRender = CreateComponent();
        
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }


    private RenderFragment CreateComponent() => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(SaySometing));
        builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(1, obj =>
        {
            SaySometing1 = (SaySometing) obj;
        });
        builder.CloseComponent();
    };

    private void ChangeText(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        SaySometing.SetLabel("Hello From SaySomething!");
        SaySometing1.SetLabel("Gutten Tag From SaySomething1!");
        ((SaySometing?)DynamicComponent?.Instance)?.SetLabel("Dobrý den from DynamicComponent");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

}
```

All three works properly and switch text to the right SaySomething.Label. But what if i want to change the SaySometing1 to new instance and keep the old instance for later and then again render it? Or how is it solved in the Blazor. As i told, I was the WPF guy and it is a new jungle for me. Or the best workaround in this technology.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  What is the purpose/context?  What I can tell you is that you - the programmer - are not in control of the creation/destruction of components.  That is the job of the Renderer.  You submit `RenderFragment`s to the Renderer.  It builds a RenderTree from the fragments and manages the components defined in the render fragments.  You can't tuck one away for safe keeping and then bring it out the hat later!

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out the data and it's state from it's presentation.  Many components demonstrate no separation of concerns: data access, data management and state, and data display are all rolled into a page.

This may be totally wide of the mark: I'll remove the answer if it is.

Take the Counter.

We can create a counter state object:

```cs
    public class CounterState
    {
        public Guid CounterId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public int Counter { get; private set; }
        public string Name => this.CounterId.ToString().Substring(0, 4);

        public void Increment()
            => Counter++;
    }
```

A Service to manage the data - in this case a list of counter objects:

```cs
public class CounterViewService
{
    public CounterState CounterState { get; private set; }

    public List<CounterState> Items { get; set; } = new();

    public event EventHandler? CounterChanged;

    public CounterViewService()
    {
       this.CounterState = new CounterState();
        Items.Add(this.CounterState);
    }

    public void SetCounter(CounterState item)
    { 
        this.CounterState = item;
        this.CounterChanged?.Invoke(item, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void AddCounterState()
    {
        var item = new CounterState();
        this.Items.Add(item);
        this.CounterState = item;
    }
    public void Increment()
    {
        this.CounterState.Increment();
        this.CounterChanged?.Invoke(this.CounterState, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Registered as a service like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CounterViewService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
```

A Counter Component to display counter state:

```cs
@inject CounterViewService Service
@implements IDisposable

<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    <h3>Counter Display @Service.CounterState.Name</h3>
    <div>Counter : @Service.CounterState.Counter</div>
    <div class="m-2">
        <button class="btn btn-light" @onclick="IncrementCount">Increment me</button>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.Service.CounterChanged += this.OnChange;

    private void IncrementCount()
    => this.Service.Increment();

    private void OnChange(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.StateHasChanged();

    public void Dispose()
        => this.Service.CounterChanged -= this.OnChange;
}
```

And finally the display page:

```cs
@inject CounterViewService Service
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<CounterDisplay />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary me-2" @onclick=this.AddCounter>AddCounter</button>
    @foreach (var counter in Service.Items)
    {
        <button class="btn btn-secondary me-2" @onclick="() => this.SelectCounter(counter)">Select Counter @(counter.CounterId.ToString().Substring(0, 4))</button>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private void AddCounter()
        => this.Service.AddCounterState();

    private void SelectCounter(CounterState counter)
        => this.Service.SetCounter(counter);
}
```

A screenshot to show it in action:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what exactly I need...

RazorParent.razor:

```
//Soemthing like ContentPresenter in the WPF
< DoesExistSomethingLikeThis Content="@RazChild" />

<a @OnClick="DisplayConfiguredRazChild">...
<a @OnClick="DisplayEmptyRazChild">...
```

RazorParent.razor@code:

```
RazorChildren RazChild {get;set;} = null;

void DisplayConfiguredRazChild()
{
RazorChildren razChild = new RazorChildren();
razChild.Configure();
RazChild = razChild;
StateHasChanged();
}

void DisplayEmptyRazChild()
{
RazorChildren razChild = new RazorChildren();
RazChild = razChild;
StateHasChanged();
}
```

Or if exist something like you create view and configure it in the code behind and then display it through the binding and still control it over the created instance... Or you must go always through the:

```
<RazorChildren @ref="_razChildRef" Param1="@RazChild.Param1"/>
```

Where you unfortunately don't control the original instance. Is it possible to create something like WPF ContentPresenter in the Blazor? Where you just bind the ComponentBase instance? It would be amazing, I know there are RenderFragment, DynamicComponent etc... But nothing can substitude this behavior where you just bind directly the ComponentBased component... Without duplicate reference instances and passing parameters in razor.